# What is a parametric value?

Tags: parameters

What is a parametric value?

A user has asked me if I can add support for parametric value for my command line app, I'm guessing it's what I'd call a variable.

Thanks

Comment: the value of a parameter

Comment: The parametric value of an alignment A may be characterized by the number of matches, mismatches, spaces and gaps it contains. (http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~gusfield/xparall/xparalhtml/node2.html)

Comment: I guess it is better to ask the user what s/he _exactly_ means by this. After all, s/he won't be any happier if you implemented something based on what _we_ think a parametric value is, if it is completely different from what s/he actually had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely they meant they'd like to pass some information into the program as a parameter on the command line.

That is, assuming your program isn't a [parametric equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation) solver or something like that where the word "parametric" could have another meaning.